# How to link/add React App.js to index.html

Tags: html, reactjs, function, indexing

How can I add my code from a React App.js file to an index.html?
I mean the main function App() with all code inside it in a html site?
Could anyone help me plz?

Comment: What do you expect by doing that? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You use the `document.getElementById()` method in the `App.js` to get an element from your index.html and then you pass it as an argument to `ReactDOM.createRoot()`

You should [read the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) for this kind of information.
Here is a code example:
https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

If you're getting started with React, maybe you should check out [Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) as it handles this kind of setup for you.